# ORA-06550 & PLS-00103 Errors when setting Oracle APEX item's default value

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

I am trying to set the default value of an item in Oracle APEX 4.2 by selecting the first value in a table having the specified `VIDEO_ID`. In the item, under the *Default* section I have set *Default Value Type* = `PL/SQL EXPRESSION`, and in the *Default Value* block I have entered

```
SELECT UNIQUE_ALLEGATION_ID 
FROM (
  SELECT UNIQUE_ALLEGATION_ID
  FROM TBL_UNIQUE_ALLEGATION
  WHERE VIDEO_ID = :P2_VIDEO_SELECT) A
WHERE ROWNUM <= 1
ORDER BY ROWNUM;
```

This code works just fine in my Oracle editor (if I replace `:P2_VIDEO_SELECT` with a value; and I am positive that `:P2_VIDEO_SELECT` is properly set).

However, when I run the page, I get the following error:

> ORA-06550: line 1, column 43: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when expecting one of the following: 
>   ( - + case mod new not null `<an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable>`
>    continue avg count current exists max min prior sql stddev sum variance execute forall merge time timestamp interval date 
>       pipe

Comment: It's not a PL/SQL expression, it's a SQL Query

Comment: oh! I guess I didn't notice that distinction

Comment: try PL/SQL function Body as Type of Default and DECLARE l_ret NUMBER; BEGIN SELECT UNIQUE_ALLEGATION_ID INTO l_ret
FROM (
  SELECT UNIQUE_ALLEGATION_ID
  FROM TBL_UNIQUE_ALLEGATION
  WHERE VIDEO_ID = :P2_VIDEO_SELECT) A
WHERE ROWNUM <= 1
ORDER BY ROWNUM; RETURN l_ret; END;

Comment: By the way, there's no point to sorting by ROWNUM, by definition it will always come out sorted, plus your query only returns one record anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that Apex attributes that accept SQL or PL/SQL fragments must be executed by the Apex at runtime, and that these must necessarily be embedded in wrapping code that must compile and execute at runtime.

So, for example, a source that is of type "PL/SQL Expression" will probably be executed in something like this:

```
declare
  temp_var varchar2(4000);
begin
  temp_var := (
SELECT UNIQUE_ALLEGATION_ID 
FROM (
  SELECT UNIQUE_ALLEGATION_ID
  FROM TBL_UNIQUE_ALLEGATION
  WHERE VIDEO_ID = :P2_VIDEO_SELECT) A
WHERE ROWNUM <= 1
ORDER BY ROWNUM
  );
  --use temp_var somewhere
end;
```

Obviously, the above code is not expected to work, which is why you're seeing an error like `ORA-06550`.